# Convert $1 DAI value to $1 USD fiat value

Tags: solidity

The DAI stable coin has **18 decimal** places.

How would one compute the math to calculate how many DAI would equal $1 USD (fiat)

In other words, does `500 * 100 ** 18` == `$500 USD` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sum `500 * 100 ** 18` would give a result of `500000000000000000000 DAI` = `$500000000000000000000 USD`

1000000000000000000 = 1 DAI = $1 USD

1 * 10 ** 18 = 1 DAI = $1 USD

500000000000000000000 = 500 DAI = $500 USD

500 * 10 ** 18 = 500 DAI = $500 USD